Troubleshooting voltage drop in dcdc power supply when driving load through H-bridge
I have designed a DC-DC power supply with an output voltage (Vout) of 1.6V and a current (Iout) of 8A.

When I connect this supply directly to a large load, it works fine.
When I use the same 1.6V output to power an H-bridge circuit to drive the same load (connected between points A and B of the H-bridge as shown in the schematic), the power supply cannot drive the load, and the output voltage drops to about 0.4V.
When I set the output voltage to 3V, the power supply can drive the load through the H-bridge, and the voltage on the load is 3V.
I also tested driving the same load through the H-bridge with another power supply, and it worked fine.
Is the problem with my DC-DC power supply or with the H-bridge circuit?
DCDC power supply



shah - Hi, Just to confirm, did you draw those schematics? If not, then to comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online & public, please [edit] the question & add the webpage/PDF/video name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + its URL). If the source is offline (e.g. printed book or private intranet) then [edit] the question & add full source details e.g. title, author, page, publisher, edition. See [help].

The maximum gate-source potential that the upper P channel MOSFETs can expect to get is -1.6 volts. If you look at that device's datasheet, you'll see this graph: -

I've put a red box around the lowest gate-source voltage the manufacturer considers to be relevant for this device when activated. You are not even close to attaining this voltage.
If you expect to deliver up to 8 amps to the load you'll need a gate-source voltage more negative than about -4 volts and, preferably -4.5 volts. You'll also to be wary of the maximum continuous power dissipation too. At 8 amps continuous you'll dissipate around 4 watts in the upper MOSFETs.

Thank you very much. Can you please suggest how to solve this problem? Do I need to change the circuit, or can you recommend a PMOS with a low VGS that can pass up to 8A of current at vout 1.6V?

@shah sorry I can't recommend a replacement MOSFET for this so, I suggest you generate a negative 5 volt DC voltage to be used exclusively for the upper MOSFET drive circuits. You will probably also need a level shifter circuit to convert IN1 and IN2 so that they are both referenced to this new negative rail. And don't forget to cite the image source in your question.

However, several aspects of the design will depend on what switching frequency you might be using in the H-bridge. For instance, with your present circuit, I expect it won't switch faster than a kHz or so but, if you expect much faster switching (circa 100 kHz) then a lot more redesign work is needed @shah

Yes, you are right. The switching frequency is not high. I just want to turn on Q3 and Q6 for two minutes and then turn them off, and then turn on Q4 and Q7 for two minutes. I have seen that the UCC27211 driver IC can use N-channel MOSFETs in both high-side and low-side configurations with independent inputs. Can UCC27211 be suitable for my application? Because this can level shift IN1 and IN2 and provide sufficient VGS for NMOS.

@shah the original question plus a follow-up question has been answered and, to prevent mission-drift (goalposts moving) we have to draw a line under this so, for your new questions you can raise a new post and open up your question to the whole floor. If we are done here, please take note of this: What should I do when someone answers my question. If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

According to the datasheet \$V_{GS(th)}\$ (\$I_D=250\$µA) of the P-channel MOSFET AOD413A is typically -2V and may be even -3V.
With a voltage of 1.6V at its source and 0V at its gate, i.e. \$V_{GS}\$ = -1.6V you are far away from turning it on.
